# How can I add 2 foreign keys from the same table? is it possible?

Tags: django, django-models

The Django documentation says that I should be able to do this as I did below:

```
class comp_name(models.Model):

  competition_type = models.ForeignKey(comptype, verbose_name='Level')
  competition_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Division',max_length = 60)
  comp_style = models.CharField(verbose_name='HT/SC', max_length = 20)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.competition_type) + " " + self.competition_name + " "+ self.comp_style

class peaople(models.Model):
  comp_name = models.ForeignKey(comp_name, blank=True,    related_name="competition_name" ,verbose_name='Division')
  heat_num = models.ForeignKey(comp_name,blank=True, related_name="heat_number")
```

However doing this gives me this error:

```
in __init__
    assert isinstance(to, six.string_types), "%s(%r) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string %r" % (self.__class__.__name__, to, RECURSIVE_RELATIONSHIP_CONSTANT)
AssertionError: ForeignKey(<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

I'm trying to add two foreign keys from the same model

Comment: what is `comptype` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for an answer to your question: **Yes**. You can add multiple foreign keys to your model that are connected to same table. Only thing you must take into consideration is giving them different `related_name` values, just like you did.

As for the error you are getting; you created a ForeignKey field named `comp_name` in `peaople` model which actually shadows the other model named `comp_name` which was defined above it. You should change the name of the field to something else, then your problem will be solved.

Note: *Assuming `comptype` is another model which defines competition type.*

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    competition_type = models.ForeignKey(CompetitionType, verbose_name='Level')
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Division',max_length=60)
    style = models.CharField(verbose_name='HT/SC', max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.competition_type, self.name, self.style)

class Competitor(models.Model):
    competition_name = models.ForeignKey(Competition, blank=True, related_name="competition_name" ,verbose_name='Division')
    heat_num = models.ForeignKey(Competition, blank=True, related_name="heat_number")
```

I'd recommend you to follow correct naming conventions. Please see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) documentation for more information.

Answer (score -2):

Foreign key should not be blank. Remove blank=True

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem.